# How to implement Megatextures

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I am interested in roughly how megatextures are/could be implemented on iOS.

In particular I am making a 2D platformer with a large (non-tiled) background and I would like to have one (precalculated, unreasonably large) image that is mapped to the background.  One option I have gone with is to chop the precalulated image into tiles, and load/unload in the background.

I am however curious about megatextures.  It would be far more convenient to map these all to one surface.  Are megatextures simply another way of phrasing what I am doing right now, or is something more cunning going on.  Is there one superlarge texture on the graphics card with multiple gltexsubimage2d calls going on?

Comment: How large is 'unreasonably large'?  Is it large in one direction and not another?  Like a side shooter?  I would definitely tile it.  The problem is going to be loading it from 'disk' more than displaying it fast enough.  And in iOS you might end up with a solution that works awesome on your iphone 5 but is too sluggish to be usable on the iphone 4.

Comment: @badweasel around 5000 pixels x 5000 pixels.  Unfortunately it is not a side scroller, it can run in any direction.

Comment: That's actually not that mega.  I'm working on a photo editing app that has all kinds of 4k x 4k textures.  The iPhone 5 and above can handle it no problem.  For the 4 and 4S I had to drop them down to 2k or it got very choppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Megatexture* is a well-developed and advanced implementation of clip-mapping technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipmap

So yes, basically it is a continuous background loading of content to be displayed and unloading of currently unused content.